# Creating matrices using for-loops in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create 2 matrices using for loops in C.

Matrix A is [18x16], where each element A[i,j] = i + j, for (i=1,...,18; j=1,...,16)
Matrix B is [16x18], where each element B[i,j] = i + 2j, for (i=1,...,16; j=1,...,18)

According to my Ubuntu (virtual machine) terminal output, I'm missing an entire row for Matrix A, and both Matrix A and B have incorrect elements at two specific places: A[17,16] and B[15,18], respectfully (please see picture below).

Code is as follows, and any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A[18][16];
int B[16][18];
int i, j; 

int main(void)
{
    // Create the A matrix
    for(i = 1; i < 18; i++){

        for(j = 1; j < 16; j++){
            A[i][j] = i + j;
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        } // End inner loop

        printf("\n");
    } // End outer loop

    printf("\n");

    // Create the B matrix
    for(i = 1; i < 16; i++){

        for(j = 1; j < 18; j++){
            B[i][j] = i + (2*j);
            printf("%d ", B[i][j]);
        } // End inner loop

        printf("\n");
    } // End outer loop
}
```

**Terminal output:**

[image]

Comment: If you declare an array `a[10]`, the index values run from `0` through `9`, inclusive.  In your code, you seem to be skipping index `0` entirely, so of course you will be missing those entries.  A quick glance at your `for` loops should make it obvious how many times they will loop, and that you're one short, right?

Comment: Yes, I did notice that, however, I think I was getting confused with the specification that both i and j started from 1. I took that too literally in the sense of implementing the for loop instead of accounting for it in the algebraic equations. Thanks to all for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Holsetly pointed out, C is 0-based.

So you need to make the following changes.

```
for(i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
        A[i][j] = i + j + 2;    // Add 1 for i, 1 for j
        printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
    } // End inner loop
    printf("\n");
} // End outer loop
```

Similarly, make changes for the other loop.

Edit: For the second loop, you need to add 3, to `i + 2j` to get the proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loops should start from `i = 0` and `j = 0` respectively.